# Get data without console.log

Tags: node.js, express

```
router.post('/add-contact-list', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let verifyToken = await auth_helper.getCompaignIdFromAdminToken(req.headers["token"]);
        await list_helper.isUserAdmin(verifyToken);
        let contact_list_name = await csv_helper.isContactListName(req.body.contact_list_name);
        let existing = await csv_helper.isContactListNameExist(contact_list_name, verifyToken.company_id);
        await csv_helper.isContactListExistLogical(existing);
        let uuid = await auth_helper.getUUID();
        await db_actions.createNewFile(uuid);
        let response = await csv_helper.addContactListInTable(uuid, verifyToken.company_id, contact_list_name);
        return res.status(200).json({response: response})
    } catch (err) {
        return campaignErrorHandler.campaignErrorHelper(err, res)
    }
});
```

How can I get all data which stores in values, like (`verifyToken,contact_list_name, existing` etc), without each time making `console.log()`. What is the better way to check logs in the application?

Comment: My suggestion is to write in a log file for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Using Console.log is the only way i have really done it in the past. This seems to be an alternative using debug which i have read about a few times but never used. Maybe this is something you could look into? not really sure if that is what you want.

https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-logging-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need this for a local development you can set up [debugger](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) for inspecting values in runtime.
2. You can use `debug` [https://github.com/visionmedia/debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug#readme) module to make your logs look nice and also to gain control over when to show them, via setting the `DEBUG` environment variable.